# Download zip file from server side and extract to a specific folder (.net 4.0)

Tags: c#, download

I am trying to write a snippet to download a zip file from server side and then extract it to a specific folder.

Something likes below, but the function ZipFile.Read always throws an exception "Cannot read that as a ZipFile", can you please advice or another solution.

I am using .net 4 and Ionic, it is easier with the .net 4.5 and higher versions. 
But I need to implement this using .net 4.0.

Thank you.

```cs
        var url = "http://localhost:30478/zip/TESTSERVICE.exe.zip";

        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            client.DownloadDataCompleted += (sender, e) =>
            {
                var inputStream = new MemoryStream(e.Result);
                inputStream.Seek(0, 0);
                var iszip = ZipFile.IsZipFile(inputStream, false);
                var zipfile = ZipFile.Read(inputStream);
            };

            client.DownloadDataAsync(new Uri(url, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
        }
```

Comment: What is the value of `iszip`? If it tells you that the file isn't a zip file, then `ZipFile.Read` probably will fail. Are you certain that the file is a valid zip file?

Comment: yes, iszip is always true

Comment: and if I use ZipFile.Read(file) instead, it works without any issue. something likes ZipFile.Read(@"C:\\TESTSERVICE.exe.zip")

Comment: oh, I changed this MemoryStream(e.Result, 0, e.Result.Lenght), it works